# Removing extra border caused by line height

Tags: html, css

I want to set left border for a paragraph, but the border has extra height because of line height. I want to remove the height of the border which exceeds the top and bottom of the text. See the screenshot:
[image]

I have tried several mothds, for example wrapping the paragraph in a div and setting the negative margin, but doesnt seem to work.

Here's simple css:

```
p{
    margin: 20px;    
    line-height: 2;    
    border-left: 5px solid green;
}
```

**Demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/0et4gq16/

Edit: The line height should not be changed.

Comment: This is tied to `line-height`, so set it to `1` and you'll see the change.

Comment: I understand the problem, I do not want to change the line height. Sorry if it was not clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just draw the line manually!

```
p{
    margin: 20px;    
    line-height: 2;
    position: relative;
}
p:after {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    width: 5px;
    background: green;
    position: absolute;
    left: -5px;
    top: 0.5em;
    bottom: 0.5em;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mem91gtd/)

Answer (score 1):

If you are not willing to change the `line-height` property, then I am afraid it is not possible.

The `margin` property defines the space between your `p` with border and the rest of the "world". But `line-height` is space **before** and **after** the line, **not between** the lines.

So, the border aligns itself as close to the text as possible, taking `line-height` in regard.

Answer (score 1):

To delete the border *above* the `p` you could add the following css:

```
p::first-line{
    line-height: 1;
}
```

this will, however shrink the line-hight between the first and the second line.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/0et4gq16/1/)**

Comment: _this will, however shrink the line-hight between the first and the second line._ - that's the point, to not change space bewteen lines.

Answer (score 1):

its not possible without altering the line height with css....you can make an image of it instead if you want so

Answer (score 1):

filthy as hell but it meets the requirements

```
<div>
    <div id="border"><div>
    <div id="content">
        <p>Nulla accumsan massa blandit ligula pellentesque dictum. Cras blandit lorem quis ultrices faucibus. Phasellus sed odio vulputate, euismod dui ac, dapibus justo. </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

with css:

```
p{
    margin: 20px;    
    line-height: 2;     
}
#border{
    display:inline-block;
    border-right:5px solid green;
    width:5px;
    margin:20px;
}
#content{
    display:inline-block;
    width:400px;
    margin:-30px 0 -30px -8px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0et4gq16/4/